# How to calculate total (sum) for add_fee value from Woo-commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, discount

I use more then one discount using `add_fee` form, for example

```
$wc_cart->add_fee( sprintf(__('fee 1', 'fee1') )."", -10, false );
$wc_cart->add_fee( sprintf(__('fee 2', 'fee1') )."", -20, false );
$wc_cart->add_fee( sprintf(__('fee 3', 'fee1') )."", -30, false );
```

I want to calculate and display the sum of whole add_fee values like

```
Total fee : 60
```

How to get `add fee` value from Woo-commerce.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below filter to calculate add_fee() total please check and add fee 2 and fee 3 too : This just for example you can modify the code according to your need

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
global $woocommerce;

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

    $percentage = 0.03;
    $taxes = array_sum($woocommerce->cart->taxes);
    $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total + $taxes ) * $percentage;   
    // Make sure that you return false here.  We can't double tax people!
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Fee 1', $surcharge, false, '' );

}
```

Comment: I implement `add_fee` method in various place in my woo-commerce system. So my question is how to calculate/sum all `add_fee` values

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get all fees and display after cart subtotal,

```
<?php
function get_all_fees() {
    $fee_object = WC()->cart->fees_api();
    $allfeedata = $fee_object->get_fees();
    $totalfee = array_sum(array_column($allfeedata, 'amount'));
    ?>
                    <tr class="fee-total">
                <th><?php esc_html_e('Total Fee', 'woocommerce'); ?></th>
                <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e('Total Fee', 'woocommerce'); ?>"><?php echo absint($totalfee); ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php
}

add_action('woocommerce_cart_totals_before_order_total', 'get_all_fees');
?>
```